# What is the difference between write and writeln?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between `write` and `writeln`?

I've searched in stackoverflow, but could not find about this. And I also searched Google where I can get the different sites results. But I believe that SO would give me the best description on these. Thanks.

Comment: Why not read the manual page?

Answer (score 6):

`writeln` adds a `\n` character to the end of the string. This almost never makes any noticeable difference when writing to an HTML document.

Answer (score 4):

`write` and `writeln` are the same function. The only difference is that `writeln` adds a new line at the end of the text.

Comment: @AlbertoSolano Be careful when you edit! Javascript is case sensitive. `document.write` and `document.writeln` exists, but not `document.Write` nor `document.WriteLn`.

Answer (score 1):

`write()` and `writeln()` methods have the same functionality

If you give for loop then it will be internally `writeln` method will break the line but in real-time we have no such outputs

because of `windows.document.write()`, `windows.document`.
writeln() methods are the problem...if we want to break the line we have to use `br`, `\n`, or `pre` tag or you can use the para tag in the script.

We have no option with `writeln()` method to break the line.

Answer (score 0):

In **javascript**, there is **no much difference** in ***write*** and ***writeln***. When writing to an HTML document, this nearly never makes a difference. Writeln only increases the readability of the code.

[image: Js used writeln. As we can see in the developer console, when the number of things increases,Writeln enhance the readability]

[image: Out pt of using write]